# Prism EventAggregator subscribing with Lambda expression vs Method name

Tags: c#, lambda, prism, eventaggregator

I am subscribing to eventAgrregator by using : eventAggregator.GetEvent.subscrinbe(..)

If I use lambda expression, it might not be called, since eventAggregator uses weak references, and somewhy it is disposed.
However when if provide a method name, it works.

Can you explain it please? 
(note - object that calls eventaggregator.getevent is not collected)

Answer (score 3):

OK. I think I found the issue.
In my lambda expression I used by mistake a local variable (.

It made the compiler to create a new object which contains the variable, and provide it as the target object to the eventAggregator. 
Then this object was removed by GC since eventAggregator use weak references.

So as long as I do not use local variables in lambda expression the target will be my original object, and it will work OK.

Comment: Yes, It is not the problem of EventAggregator, but the nature of local variable in lambda expression. I had same issue in 2020. :)